# Distribuir funciones entre nodos a través de sockets en Rust

Tags: socket, rust

Estoy planteando una arquitectura donde tengo una máquina que cumple el rol de **Master** y otras máquinas con el de **Worker** conectadas a través de **sockets**. Quiero poder transmitir desde el Master hacia los Workers una función a ejecutar. Esta función estaría dentro de una estructura con otros datos extra como sugiere el siguiente esquema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el Master envía a los Workers una función **cualquiera** (en la imagen como `aFunction` que puede tomar cualquier parametro, incluso funciones) y este la debe ejecutar. Como la función no se conoce de antemano y puede ser dinámica no puedo implementar todas las posibles altenativas en el Worker para después desde el Master enviar una simple orden. Estuve planteando varias estrategias, pero como soy nuevo en Rust y todavía no termino [el libro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/index.html) no se si son factibles:

- Envíar la función con todos sus parámetros, ambas partes serializadas como string y que el Worker haga un
  eval del mismo: no se si existe esa función en Rust, ni los inconvenientes en materia de seguridad que esta solución podría conllevar.
- Seguir el planteo de [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org) que compila la función a correr en un *.jar* y distribuye ese archivo a través de la red a todos los Workers para que estos importen dicho *.jar* y lo llamen estáticamente. No se si se puede realizar ese tipo de importación en Rust para llamar a los métodos de manera estática a partir de un archivo compilado.

No se me ocurren otras alternativas, si alguien pudiera arrojarme un poco de luz sobre el asunto se lo agradecería. Estuve buscando variantes en otros lenguajes como Python pero no encuentro soluciones que distribuyan funcionalidad mediante sockets.

Comment: Talvez este [artículo](https://www.willusher.io/2016/01/02/distributed-rendering-with-rust-and-mio) puede ayudar

Comment: Muchas gracias!